# isotopy inverse embeddings vs. diffeomorphisms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

I would like to find an example, if one exists, of manifolds $M$ and $N$ with embeddings $f:M\to N$ and $g:N\to M$ such that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both isotopic (i.e. homotopic through embeddings) to the respective identities, yet the interiors of $M$ and $N$ are not diffeomorphic. Obviously, $M$ and $N$ cannot be closed. You may assume that the manifolds have no boundary, but I would also be interested in compact examples.

By the way: in the other direction, are there conditions under which $M$ and $N$ are necessarily diffeomorphic if $f$ and $g$ as above exist?

Comment: Would small exotic $\mathbb R^4$s work?

Comment: @Zack: I was actually thinking of simply using the Whitehead manifold together with its embedding into ${\mathbb R}^3$, but I know next to nothing about the space of self-embeddings of the Whitehead manifold.

Comment: @Ricardo: Embedding a Whitehead manifold W to an open ball in $R^3$ would not work. (Since an isotopy would yield a sequence of 2-spheres which exit the end of W, which is impossible.) 

Comment: @Misha: I don't see the contradiction. If you are thinking about the case $Whitehead \subset Ball \subset Whitehead$, one can imagine a highly nonproper isotopy, whose first half pierces some of the sphere but not the rest, and ends with a self embedding of Whitehead that does not have compact closure but also does not contain the sphere; then the 2nd half of the isotopy continues to the identity map. This avoids the sequence of 2-spheres you are concerned about. A similar imaginary isotopy avoids this contradiction in the case $Ball \subset Whitehead \subset Ball$.

Comment: Does your edit mean you invite examples with boundary? A closed interval and an open interval. For a compact example, take manifolds that are $h$-cobordant but not diffeomorphic. Crossing with an open interval gives diffeomorphic manifolds and crossing with a closed interval gives an example of your property.

Comment: @Lee: The image of $Whitehead\subset Ball\subset Whitehead$ doesn't contain any nonlocal knots.

Comment: @Ben: Thank you for pointing out that my edit introduced an obvious counter-example. I partially reversed the edit to avoid your counter-examples.

Comment: A knot in a $3$-manifold is called nonlocal if it is not contained in any closed ball. An open $3$-manifold containing no nonlocal knots is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$, http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-01/S0002-9939-1971-0271919-1/ so Zack's remark suffices to answer the 3-dimensional case of the question. To see an explicit nonlocal knot in the Whitehead manifold $W$ it suffices to know that the $n$th Whitehead link is nontrivial (and this is how Whitehead originally proved that $W\not\cong\Bbb R^3$).

Comment: ("nontrivial" should be "non-split")

Comment: @Sergey and @Zack: I have a perhaps silly question. How do you guarantee that non-local knots are preserved under isotopies (through embeddings, not necessarily diffeomorphisms) of the identity?

Comment: @Zack: I think the issue with your clever suggestion is that if you have an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ E, and embeddings $E\subset \mathbb{R}^4\subset E$, then how do you know that the induced embedding $E\subset E$ is smoothly isotopic to the identity? (I say clever because when I first read it I upvoted it!). In any case, I think my answer shows that it cannot be. 

Comment: Ricardo: by the isotopy extension theorem (see Agol's answer). A non-local knot in $W$ is smoothly isotopic to a knot in $h(W)\subset B\subset W$; by the isotopy extension theorem this isotopy is covered by a smooth isotopy of $W$. Less trivially, Smythe proved that a knot in a $3$-manifold, PL isotopic to the unknot (by a possibly non-locally-flat PL isotopy), is contained in a ball (see Lemma 2.2 in http://arxiv.org/abs/math.GT/0103114 ). By the way, I of course meant to say that Zack's remark suffices to answer the case $M=\Bbb R^3$ of your question, not the full 3D case.

Comment: @Sergey: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here I'll prove that $M$ and $N$ must be diffeomorphic under your hypotheses (I'll assume that $M$ and $N$ are open, i.e. no boundary).

Consider the direct limit (see below)  $X= M \overset{f}{\to} N \overset{g}{\to} M \overset{f}{\to} N \overset{g}{\to}\cdots$. By this, I mean the union $M \times \mathbb{N} \sqcup N\times \mathbb{N}$ modulo the identifications $(m,k)\sim (f(m),k), (n,k)\sim (g(n),k+1)$, for $m\in M, n\in N, k\in \mathbb{N}$.  Then $X$ is a smooth manifold, since it is a nested union of smooth manifolds. Similarly, we have the direct limit $Y=N \overset{g}{\to} M \overset{f}{\to} N \overset{g}{\to}\cdots$. Clearly, $X \cong Y$, since the direct limit depends only on the tail of the sequence. Also, $X$ (and therefore $Y$) is diffeomorphic to the direct limits  $ M \overset{g\circ f}{\to} M \overset{g\circ f}{\to} M \overset{g\circ f}{\to}\cdots$ and $N\overset{f\circ g}{\to} N\overset{f\circ g}{\to} N\overset{f\circ g}{\to}\cdots$.

**Claim:** If $F:M\to M$ is isotopic to the identity, then the direct limit $M\overset{F}{\to} M\overset{F}{\to} M\overset{F}{\to} \cdots \cong M$.

By the above discussion, this implies that $M\cong N$.

To prove the claim, let $F_t:M\to M, t\in [0,1]$ be an isotopy of $F$ to the identity, so $F_1=F$, and $F_0=Id$. Take an exhaustion of $M$ by smooth compact submanifolds with boundary $K_1\subset K_2\subset K_3 \subset \cdots$, so that $F([0,1]\times K_i)\subset int(K_{i+1})$, $K_i\subset int(K_{i+1})$, and $\cup K_i=M$. The we see that $X_t = M\overset{F_t}{\to} M\overset{F_t}{\to}M\overset{F_t}{\to}\cdots$ is diffeomorphic to $Y_t= K_2 \overset{F_t}{\to} K_4 \overset{F_t}{\to} K_6 \overset{F_t}{\to} \cdots$ for all $t$ (where we really meant $F_{t| K_{2i}}$ in the maps of this direct limit and topologized by the inclusion of interiors). To see this, note that $X_t$ is a quotient of $M\times \mathbb{N}$, which is exhausted by $\{(K_k,i), k,i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Since $Y_t\subset X_t$, we need only show that each point of $X_t$ is in $Y_t$. Suppose $x\in X_t$, then $x$ is the image of some $x'\in (K_k,i)$ for some $k,i$. If $k\leq 2i$, then $x'\in (K_{2i},i)$, so we see that $x\in Y_t$. Otherwise, $k>2i$ and we see that $(K_k,i) \overset{F_t}{\subset}(K_{k+1},i+1) \overset{F_t}{\subset} \cdots \overset{F_t}{\subset} (K_{2k-2i},k-i)$ after taking the quotient, so $x\in Y_t$.

By the [Isotopy Extension Theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=iSvnvOodWl8C&lpg=PP1&dq=hirsch%2520differential%2520topology&pg=PA180#v=onepage&q&f=false), one may see that $Y_0 \cong Y_1$. This gives the desired diffeomorphism $M\cong M\overset{F}{\to} M\overset{F}{\to} M\overset{F}{\to} \cdots $.

We actually use the isotopy extension theorem by induction. We want to find a sequence of diffeomorphisms $G^i: K_{2i}\to K_{2i}$ so that $G^{i+1}_{|K_{2i}} = F\circ G^i$. This immediately gives the diffeomorphism

$$\begin{matrix} Y_1= K_2 & \overset{F}{\to} & K_4 & \overset{F}{\to} &  K_6 & \overset{F}{\to} & \cdots\\
 G^1 \uparrow  &  &G^2\uparrow  &  &G^3\uparrow  & & \\ 
Y_0= K_2 & \hookrightarrow &  K_4 & \hookrightarrow & K_6 & \hookrightarrow &  \cdots
\end{matrix}$$

We will actually construct a diffeotopy $G^i_t:K_{2i}\to K_{2i}, t\in [0,1]$ such that  $G^{i+1}_{t|K_{2i}}=F_t\circ G^i_t$, where $G^i_0=Id$, and then set $G^i=G^i_1$ for the desired diffeomorphism.

Let $G^1_t=Id$. Suppose we have constructed $G^i_t$ by induction, so that $G^i_0=Id$, $G^i_{t|K_{2i-2}}=F_t \circ G^{i-1}_t$, $t\in [0,1]$. Then $F_t\circ G^i_t: K_{2i}\to int(K_{2i+2})$ is an isotopy from $F_0\circ G^i_0=Id$ to $F_1\circ G^i_1=F\circ G^i_1$. By the isotopy extension theorem, there exists a diffeotopy $G^{i+1}_t: K_{2i+2}\to K_{2i+2}$ such that $G^{i+1}_0=Id$, and $G^{i+1}_{t|K_{2i}}=F_t\circ G^i_t$, with compact support in $int(K_{2i+2})$. This completes the proof.

**Addendum:** I'll add some explanation of direct limits. Consider a sequence of smooth embeddings of open manifolds $X_i \overset{f_i}{\to} X_{i+1}$. By the direct limit $X$ of $X_1\overset{f_1}{\to} X_2 \overset{f_2}{\to} X_3 \cdots$, I mean the quotient of $X_1\sqcup X_2 \sqcup X_3 \sqcup \cdots$ with respect to the equivalence relation generated by $x_i \sim f_i(x_i)$ for all $x_i \in X_i, i\in \mathbb{N}$. Then there is a natural embedding of $X_i \hookrightarrow X$ for all $i$, in such a way that $X= \cup_i X_i$, and one gives $X$ the structure of a smooth manifold by taking the atlas of charts generated by the charts of each $X_i$.

The space $X$ is determined by the direct limit of any subsequence $\{ X_{i_j}\}$, with maps $F_j: X_{i_j}\to X_{i_{j+1}}$ defined by $F_j=f_{i_{j+1}-1}\circ \cdots \circ f_{i_j}$. One may therefore verify that two direct limits are diffeomorphic if there are compatible diffeos. between subsequences, which justifies some of the arguments above.

Comment: Do you consider direct limits in the category of topological spaces?  If so, I don't quite follow in what sense each of your homeomorphisms between direct limits is supposed to be a diffeomorphism. You can transfer the smooth structure from a finite stage to the limit when they are homeomorphic, but is that finite stage even or odd?

Comment: @Agol: Thanks for the answer. It looks good to me. I will wait a little while to see what others say. It is certainly a beautiful idea. I was trying to make an analogy with the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem but kept coming short because the manifolds were not compact (so I could not apply some isotopy extension). Your method seems to cleverly realize that vague intuition. Just a couple of silly remarks: (1) I think you meant $(K_{2k-2i},k-2i)$ at the end of the fifth paragraph. (2) Perhaps you should redefine $Y_t$ to be the colimit of the interiors of $K_{2i}$, ...

Comment: @ Ricardo: Addressing your remarks (1) I think I meant $k-i$, since it is $i+ k-2i$, where by hypothesis $k-2i>0$  (2) since $K_{2i} \subset int(K_{2i+2})$, I think it doesn't matter, but maybe I should add a remark about this. 

Comment: ... or at least make it clear that is how you obtain the differential structure on $Y_t$.

Comment: @Agol: You are right about my remark (1)... It seems I cannot count... Sorry.

Comment: Agol: I now see that your argument works, if corrected so as to use direct limit in the category of smooth manifolds and their open smooth embeddings (along with an easy lemma that it does exist). I interpret your comments as meant to say that this direct limit is concrete not only over the category of sets, but also over the category of topological spaces (ie, commutes with the corresponding forgetful functor). This is really a technical matter, but your implicit reference to topological direct limits ("Then $X$ is a smooth manifold") confused me enough to doubt the validity of your proof. 